# Creating a Dom element for form onsubmit="return function(x)"

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to create a DOM element of a form that has "return function(input)" as it's onsubmit. But the function doesn't see, to be called

```
function AddComment(id) {
    alert(id);
    return false;
}
```

Above is the function that should be called. Below is the DOM element's code where I generate the onsubmit event:

```
...
form.onsubmit = 'return AddComment('+ place.place_id+')';
...
```

Comment: `form.onsubmit` should be a reference to a function, not a string.

Comment: Use `form.onsubmit = function() { return AddComment(place.place_id); };`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `form.onsubmit` property expects a function reference instead of a string containing code to be evaluated.

You could create a wrapper function and assign that instead:

```
form.onsubmit = function() {
    return AddComment(place.place_id);
};
```

Comment: Such a simple solution, I didn't even think of doing it like that thanx!